# Performance of checking "expanded list" equality

Tags: python

I need to check whether a given list is equal to the result of substituting some lists for some elements in another list. Concretely, I have a dictionary, say `f = {'o': ['a', 'b'], 'l': ['z'], 'x': ['y']}` and a list `list1 = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, so I want to check if some `list2` is equal to `['H', 'e', 'z', 'z', 'a', 'b']`.

Below, I first write a function `apply` to compute the image of `list1` under `f`.  Then, it suffices to write `list2 == apply(list1, f)`.  Since this function will be called thousands of times in my program, I need to make it very fast.  Therefore, I thought of the second function below, which should be faster but turns out not to be.  So my questions (detailed below) are: why? And: is there a faster method?

First function:

```
def apply(l, f):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        if x in f:
            result.extend(f[x])
        else:
            result.append(x)
    return result
```

Second function:

```
def apply_equal(list1, f, list2):
    i = 0
    for x in list1:
        if x in f:
            sublist = f[x]
            length = len(sublist)
            if list2[i:i + length] != substmt:
                return False
            i += length
        else:
            if list2[i] != x:
                return False
            i += 1
    return i == len(list2)
```

I thought the second method would be faster since it does not construct the list which is the image of the first list by the function and then checks equality with the second list. On the contrary, it checks equality "on the fly" without constructing a new list. So I was surprised to see that it is not faster (and even: a bit slower).  For the record: `list1`, `list2`, and the lists which are values in the dictionary are all small (typically under 50 elements), as well as the number of keys of the dictionary.

So my questions are: why isn't the second method faster ? And: are there ways to do this faster (possibly using other data structures)?

**Edit** in response to the comments: `list1` and `list2` will most often be different, but `f` may be common to some of them. Typically, there could be around 100,000 checks in batches of around 50 consecutive checks with a common `f`. The elements of the lists are short strings. It is expected that all checks return True (so the whole lists have to be iterated over).

Comment: Your second function avoids the creation of the `result` list - at the cost of creating a bunch of sublists (every time you slice `list2`).  As for optimization, are any of `f`, `list1`, or `list2` the same for all (or at least many) of your thousands of calls?  A seldom-changing parameter may allow for some pre-calculation to be done that speeds up subsequent tests using the same value.

Comment: What's fast depends on the data. Can you provide it, or something equivalent (regarding sizes and how early there are differences and how many characters are in the dict)?

Comment: @jasonharper But a slice is only a shallow copy, isn't it ? Doesn't that make it faster to obtain ? (I'm using "obtain" versus "create" purposefully)

Comment: Calling `apply` at all may be a bottleneck; you may want to inline it with something like `list2 == list(chain.from_iterable(f[x] if x in f else (x,) for x in list1))`.

Comment: @chepner Your proposal is a tiny bit slower than my slower method.

Comment: Hm, I was afraid of that. Too much overhead in moving from lists to arbitrary iterables.

Comment: I have a few solutions, depending on the data they're sometimes faster. Can we get useful benchmarking data?

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy. Could you give them as an answer? I tried to give some idea about the data in the edit to my question.  Going further would require actual data (or something very close to it) and I should at least talk to other persons before sharing it.

Comment: The actual data would of course be ideal, but something close to it could be great as well. Just the single tiny case shown in the question isn't very useful, and your description of the real data isn't quite enough to replicate it (plus it would be work to do, which at least I don't want to do unless I feel confident that it's meaningful). But I did post an answer with some things now and leave it to you to measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without proper data for benchmarking it's hard to say, so I tested various solutions with various "sizes" of data.

1. Replacing `result.extend(f[x])` with `result += f[x]` always made it faster.
2. This was faster for longer lists (using `itertools.chain`):

   ```
   list2 == list(chain.from_iterable(map(f.get, list1, zip(list1))))
   ```
3. If the data allows it, explicitly storing all possible keys and always accessing with `f[x]` would speed it up. That is, set `f[k] = k,` for all "missing" keys in advance, so you don't have to check with `in` or use `get`.

Comment: Thanks @Kelly. 3. is not possible since, while f has few keys, there would be too many "potential keys", so adding `(k, f[k])` for all possible k would make it huge.  Since my lists are small, 2. will probably not be beneficial, though I will try it. I tried 1. and it is indeed faster ! I do not know how this is compiled under the hood, but I find it strange that they behave differently. By the way: why are there two synonyms `l.extend(x)` and `l += x`. Isn't this contrary to python's "there should be only one reasonable way to do a given task"?

Comment: @user0 The `+=` [becomes INPLACE_ADD](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCEls5iLC0joAbGGeqJeakVJal6KRpKmuiZXQVFmXomGJpK0gratQpK65v//AA), which is done more directly than the loading and calling of the `extend` method.

Comment: Regarding "there should be only one reasonable way to do a given task": I think you made that up, even the mighty [Google hasn't heard of that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22there+should+be+only+one+reasonable+way+to+do+a+given+task%22) :-P. And while the Zen does say something like it, that's somewhat the *ideal*, but isn't the case for *many* things.

Comment: Thanks. I found the quote: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 1):

You need to use profiling tools like [scalene](https://github.com/emeryberger/scalene) to see what's slow in your code, don't try to guess.

In case you want to read it, I was able to produce an even slower version based on your idea of stoping as soon as possible, but while keeping the first readable `apply` implementation:

```py
def apply(l, f):
    for x in l:
        if x in f:
            yield from f[x]
        else:
            yield x


def apply_equal(l1, f, l2):
    return all(left == right for left, right in zip(apply(l1, f), l2, strict=True))
```

Beware it needs Python 3.10 for zip's `strict=True`.

As the comments told, speed highly depends on your data here, constructing the whole list may look faster on small datasets, but halting soon may be faster on a bigger list.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it is profiling with scalene that showed me that in my code, the bottleneck was `apply`. I'll see if I can think of a larger refactoring which makes fewer calls to it...